# Slow computer performance on a decent configuration

Tags: windows-7

I bought a new computer like a year ago, and I must say that I am unhappy. Although I chose the best components that were available in my country then, my computer's performance drives me to madness. My configuration is this:
Intel core i3-530 2.93 GHz
4GB 1333 MHz RAM
ATI Radeon HD 5550 1 GB DD3 video card
WDC Caviar Green WD15EARS 1.5 TB

Now, I suspect that the hard drive is causing those troubles. I was not the one who chose it, but I liked it because of the huge amount of space, although I did not know anything about it's performance. Later on, I found out about it's bad performance, and read many comments on the same topic. If that is not the reason, I would be real thankful if you could provide me with some additional details. In case that other information about my computer is needed, feel free to ask me.

To explain this issue a bit, I will say that the computer is slow pretty much the whole time. The worse is when I start it up, the first 10 minutes are so bad, that even Mozilla lags, and is real annoying to use. Mozilla actually continues to lag even after that, but much rarer. Mozilla as far as I know should be running like a charm on a configuration like this, and even my laptop which is like then times worse than this runs Mozilla without lagging at all, on start up or after working for some time.

Regarding games, they do run good. I am able to run pretty good games on high resolution with high details, although the video card crashes some times. I've overclocked the video card using ATI Catalyst Center, as so far I haven't experienced any problems like overheating.

The computer needs like 5 minutes to start up, or like 15 if you want to use it without wanting to get annoyed.

Comment: You forgot to describe your problem. Is the computer slow to start up? Slow to launch applications? Slow to load web pages? Are productivity applications slow? Are frame rates low in games? We have no idea what your actual issue is.

Comment: What is your Windows Experience Index Score and Subscores?

Comment: Green drives are not usually suggested for boot drives.

Comment: Have you tried the Windows Experience Index within Windows 7 to see the rating of your components?  You can check this by opening the control panel and going to **System and Security** and clicking **Check the Windows Experience Index**.  You can then run the assessment by clicking the button in the bottom-right.

Comment: My total score is 5.9 - Processor [6.9], RAM [5.9], Graphics [6.8], HDD [5.9]. I did not know anything about Green drives then, but it's too late now.

Comment: Your drive's score is exactly the same as mine (500gb Seagate from a few years ago) but I don't experience any issues.  Has the system been running poorly since the very first day you had it or has this accumulated over time?

Comment: The system has been running poorly since the very first day. I experience real slow data transfer from one partition to other, although my system is freshly installed.

Comment: @user726049 Have you tried running [Data Lifeguard Diagnostic](http://support.wdc.com/product/download.asp?groupid=605&sid=3&lang=en) to see how the drive is performing?

Comment: WEI figures look ok. Make sure you don't have more than one anti-virus set to scan files in real time or that your av package isn't set to scan your whole hard-disk every time you start windows and also make sure you don't have any viruses You could try downloading Soluto from http://www.soluto.com/Download which can help analyse startup issues. Also if you start TaskManager immediately windows starts and look at resource monitor you can see cpu and disk activity by process.

Comment: I will trie the Data Lifeguard Diagnostic and Soluto now. Nope, I have only Avast installed, and no viruses at all.

Comment: I did the quick test of Data Lifeguard Diagnostic, and it passed. Right now, I have no time to run the extend one.

Comment: When you get a chance I suggest you run the extended one and post the results here for us.  If something is really off with the diagnostics then I'd RMA the drive.

Answer (score 0):

Have you changed your Power Settings to High Performance, at all? Often on Windows Vista and 7, this can have a dramatic effect on performance, especially with "green" components.

For reference, I have a green WD 1.5TB drive and it does spin down quite frequently, so you may want to look for a blue or black WD drive (if the flooding in Thailand hasn't put those drives out of your budget) for booting up.

For general usage though, the drive isn't *too* slow, once it gets going after the five-to-ten second spin-up period.

Answer (score 0):

Its possible you may have so many unnecessary processes getting started at startup. Use CCleaner to get rid of temporary files. Stop unnecessary processes which starts at winows stratup from  CCleaner or Goto run-> services.msc and stop unwanted process which starts up automatically..

Link : https://kb.wisc.edu/helpdesk/page.php?id=1688